# A Hard Number Theory Problem $f(n+1)=f(n)+2^{f(n)}$

Tags: number-theory

> Define a function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\quad$ by $\begin{cases}f(1)=1\\f(n+1)=f(n)+2^{f(n)}\ \text{ for every integer }n\end{cases}$
>
> Prove that $f(1),f(2),\cdots,f(3^{2013})$ leave distinct remainders when divided by $3^{2013}$

I got this problem from a telegram group posted by someone who did not reveal the source of the problem.

My approach : After seeing this problem I tried to make a list of values but coudn't proceed for much longer as soon it reaches higher for large values of 2^n . But one thing is clear that this function is clearly increasing for positive. Finding the closed form for the recurrence seems not possible. So after this I dont have any ideas.

I request a help in this problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the there is nothing special about the 2013, except that this problem was first posted in that year. So I expect the same will still be true if we replace the 2013 with 4 or 5. In this case it is possible to follow your original plan and make a full list of values. Whether this will turn out to be useful remains to be seen of course

Comment: Yeah exactly. I too think it can be kind of generalised to any n.

Comment: please use a meaningful title and don't post a picture of the problem.

Comment: Iam not very comfortable and used to using LateX. And moreover I think the picture is clear enough to be understood.

Comment: The more interesting question is if we can replace the 3 with an arbitrary number (or perhaps an arbitrary odd number) too or that it really must be 3. This is something we can check by trial and error.

Comment: @Vincent I guess that the solution exhibits such a generalization anyway. I think, we can prove much more and the claim is only a special case. Does not make it easier however.

Comment: @MycroftHolmes I do not think that the title is bad, but if you want to follow miracle173's comment you can choose something like "why are the remainders in this sequence distinct ?"

Comment: I will surely follow this from next time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We first point out a result that's essential here: $2^a \equiv 2^b \text{ mod } 3^n$ if and only if $2 \cdot 3^{n-1} | a-b$. This is because $2^{3^n} \equiv -1 \text{ (mod } 3^{n+1}$).(easily proved using induction)

Next we prove the following claim by induction on $m$:
\begin{equation}
f(i) \equiv f(j) \text{ (mod $3^m$)} \text{ if and only if } i \equiv j \text{ (mod $3^m$)}.
\end{equation}

Assume it is true for $m$, then the set of any consecutive $3^m$ terms of $f(n)$ mod $3^m$ is $\{ 0, 1, \cdots, 3^m-1 \}$. (also notice all $f(n)$ are odd.)
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(i+3^m)-f(i) & = 2^{f(i)} + 2^{f(i+1)} + \cdots + 2^{f(i+3^m-1)} \\
& \equiv 2^1+2^3+\cdots+2^{2 \cdot 3^m-1} \\
& = 2 \cdot \frac{2^{2\cdot 3^m}-1}{2^2-1} \equiv 2 \cdot 3^m \text{ (mod $3^{m+1}$)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
With this, it follows case $m+1$ is true.

Comment: Thank you . It has been most helpful